# Button Save disabled in ABAP Editor for Auto Completion

Tags: editor, abap

Recently I've installed the SAPGUI, and I want to turn on the auto-completion option "Suggest Non-Keywords from the Text".

But the button to save this setting is disabled.

How to save the setting?

[image: Editor options of SAP GUI backend ABAP editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem, I just uninstall and install the SAPGUI, and it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a permission problem preventing the SAPGUI from performing updates.

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\ABAP EDITOR\Settings.xml

Check how SAPGUI is Launched.   Try  launching with ADMIN rights.
Does your organisation restrict roaming profiles ?

Perhaps an admin guy there knows why you cant update
...AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\ABAP EDITOR\Settings.xml

```
<Code_Completion>
    <AutoCompletion>1</AutoCompletion>
    <AutoOpen>0</AutoOpen>
    <TimeOpen>1500</TimeOpen>
    <UseExternalDict>0</UseExternalDict>
    <UseLocalDict>1</UseLocalDict>
    <QuickInfo>1</QuickInfo>
    <CodeHints>1</CodeHints>
    <KKCharsNum>2</KKCharsNum>
    <AutoHideToolTip>1</AutoHideToolTip>
    <AutoHideDelay>3000</AutoHideDelay>
    <UseSimpleAutocomp>1</UseSimpleAutocomp>         <<<<<< set this to 1
    <CurrentScope>1</CurrentScope>
    <Transparency>100</Transparency>
    <HoveringDelay>500</HoveringDelay>
    <HoveringInfo>1</HoveringInfo>
    <CodeHintAgreeByReturn>0</CodeHintAgreeByReturn>
</Code_Completion>
```